# Which are the int values of getMajorDeviceClass in J2ME?

Tags: bluetooth, java-me

I know that for detect the kind of device, `DeviceClass` is used:

```
void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice btDevice, DeviceClass cod)
```

I can use `cod.getMajorDeviceClass()` but I don't know which are the int values that corresponds to a "Computer", "Phone", **...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major and Minor values are defined in Bluetooth specification. At [this page](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/baseband) you have an overall explanation of the values:

> The Major Device Class segment is the highest level of granularity for
>   defining a Bluetooth device. A device's main function determines its
>   Major Class assignment. There are 32 major classes.

The values are well documented on Android's [BluetoothClass.Device.Major](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major.html). For example:

```
public static final int COMPUTER = 0x100;
public static final int PHONE = 0x200;
```

You can copy these definitions to your Java ME code and use a simple comparison to check:

```
if (cod.getMajorDeviceClass() == COMPUTER) {
  // ...
} else if (cod.getMajorDeviceClass() == PHONE) {
  // ...
}
```